# How to Validate locationcode When the location is all set?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi guys i Have A newbie problem
I want to  validate my location code when the location code is all ready taken 
the php tell me that the location code is exist
how to do this with PHP thanks in advance...

```
if(isset($_POST['addbtn'])){

    $lcode = $_POST['locationcode'];
    $ladd  = $_POST['locationadd'];

     $stationadd =  $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_station (locationcode,locationaddress)
                                     VALUES  (?,?)");

    $stationadd->bind_param('is',$lcode,$ladd);
    $stationadd->execute();
    $stationadd->close();
    $mysqli->close();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Do it in two ways:

**1. After Form POST:**
You have to write select query for checking "locationcode" from existing database details and if it matches with your DB value then you dont execute INSERT query directly redirect to your previous form along with error msg.

**2. AJAX :**
It will help you to detect your inserting "locationcode" is present in your DB or not without submitting form..if it "locationcode" already present in DB then popup alert msg and return false..

**Tutorial :**
[www.ajax-tutor.com/post-data-server.html](http://www.ajax-tutor.com/post-data-server.html)

Comment: Hi sir @Ashish
Thanks..
How to validate using ajax
sorry because I'm New in web developing..

Comment: i have search simplest tutorial for you as you are new, http://www.ajax-tutor.com/post-data-server.html

Comment: Waw Thanks For this Example..
thank You very much
its ok to copy this example?

Comment: sure..go ahead..even you can do it on button click or on blur event..best of luck